# jqplot array data refactor code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I have the below method i jquery.
The if blocks to call jqplot are not looking good.
is there a better way to handle this?

```
onDealerSuccess: function (graphData, graphsDrpDwn, grphOneID, grphTwoID) {
        /// <summary>This method is called on success of ajax call for dealer breakdown tab </summary>
        /// <summary> This makes the necessary calls and plots the graph and bind the grid data </summary>

        if (!graphData)
            return;
        var
            grdYTcks = graphData["grdYTicks"].split(","),
            grdXTcks = graphData["grdXTicks"].split(","),
            mtrcXTcks = graphData["metricXTicks"].split(","),
            mtrcYTcks = jQuery.parseJSON(graphData["metricYTicks"]),
            YAxisLbl = "Grade";

        // plot dealer graph
        $.jqplot(grphOneID, [grdYTcks], YC.getGraphOpts(grdXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.plotColors)).replot();

        YAxisLbl = "Points";

        // Sangeetha - Need to work on refactoring the below code
        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 1)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 2)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 3)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 4)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 5)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 6)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 7)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 8)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 9)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 10)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8], mtrcYTcks[9]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 11)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8], mtrcYTcks[9], mtrcYTcks[10]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 12)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8], mtrcYTcks[9], mtrcYTcks[10], mtrcYTcks[11]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 13)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8], mtrcYTcks[9], mtrcYTcks[10], mtrcYTcks[11], mtrcYTcks[12]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        if (mtrcYTcks.length === 14)
            $.jqplot(grphTwoID, [mtrcYTcks[0], mtrcYTcks[1], mtrcYTcks[2], mtrcYTcks[3], mtrcYTcks[4], mtrcYTcks[5], mtrcYTcks[6], mtrcYTcks[7], mtrcYTcks[8], mtrcYTcks[9], mtrcYTcks[10], mtrcYTcks[11], mtrcYTcks[12], mtrcYTcks[13]], YC.getGraphOpts(mtrcXTcks, YAxisLbl, m_CompositeReport.stdColors)).replot();

        YC.assignOvrw(graphData);
        YC.bindGrid(graphData);
    },
```